Editor can't edit the data source created by Google App Script
So we create our own connector for Looker Studio using Google App Script. Let say We create the connector using abcde@gmail.com in Google App Script.
we also use abcde@gmail.com as the owner of the Looker Studio file. abcde@gmail.com can easily edit the data source created by Google App Script previously.

but when an editor (let say the editor using xxxxxxx@gmail.com) want to edit the data source, it cant be edited. it will show an error : unknown connector like this


"There was an error retrieving this Add-on's configuration"

I assume it relates to the access or permission, but how to give the permission for connector created by Google App Script?
I have tried to read this "There was an error retrieving this Add-on's configuration"
it is said that it relates getConfig method in Google App Script. but what code do I have to write? please help

Verify whether your data source is using Viewer or Owner credentials.

@aliizadi how to do that? where should I check?

https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/6371135#zippy=%2Cin-this-article
